# How do you change the audio source when clicking on an option, from a select?

Tags: javascript, events, audio

I have an array of sounds, that I attribute to the an empty audio
which looks like this :

```
<audio id = "audio4" controls>
    <source id = "audioSourceAside" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

I added a "change" Event Listener to every option I want to use, but it doesn't work, the audio source stays greyed out, even if I force it to get a source via chrome's console, it's greyed out.

Comment: Where do you set `.src` at `<source>` element? What do you mean by "it's greyed out"?

Comment: var aSoundPlayer = document.querySelectorAll("audio source");

Comment: That does not set `src` attribute, `document.querySelectorAll("audio source")` only gets the `<source>` element.

Comment: yes, but since there are many, I use, for exemple aSoundPlayer[3].src

Comment: What is result?

Comment: I get the src, but it dosen't appear on the page, that's what I explained earlier, the audio is still greyed out

Comment: Not gathering what you mean. What do you mean by "greyed out"?

Comment: Since the audio dosen't have a source, at the beginning, it's greyed out, I can't click on the "play" arrow, but even when it has a source, it's greyed out. It's like it's source is empty.

Comment: Call `.load()` on `<audio>` element.

Answer (score 0):

Use `change` event attached to `<select>` element. Within `change` handler, call `.pause()` on `<audio>` node, set `.src` of `<source>` element to `.value` of `<select>` element, call `.load()`, then call `.play()` on `AudioNode`.

```js
var select = document.querySelector("select");
var audio = document.querySelector("audio");
var source = audio.querySelector("source");
select.onchange = function() {
  audio.pause();
  source.src = this.value;
  audio.load();
  audio.play();
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option>Select audio to play</option>
  <option value="https://ia600305.us.archive.org/30/items/return_201605/return.mp3">RETURN by smiling cynic </option>
  <option value="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/be/Hidden_Tribe_-_Didgeridoo_1_Live.ogg">Didgeridoo 1 Live by Hidden Tribe</option>
</select>
<br>
<audio id="audio4" controls>
<source id="audioSourceAside">
</audio>
```

Comment: that works! But everytime you want to stop the sound, it gives you an error.. that isn't too great

Comment: Well, since your code changes the sources and the first option removes the src and gives it an undefined source, it says something like :

    net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Comment: The first `<option>` can be removed. You can alternatively use `<label>` element placed before or adjacent to `<select>` element to provide notification to user as to what they are selecting an option for, if use `if` condition within `change` event to only set `.src` if selected option index is not `0` or selected option `.value` is not equal to "Select audio to play"